# Do we need PBFT algorithm support in permissioned Block chain networks?

Tags: blockchain, fault-tolerance, consensus

I am new to BCT. My question is why do we need a consensus algorithm such as PBFT in a permission based Block chain network where the nodes are trusted nodes. Is it only to find a way when nodes fail or is there any other use case.  Can anyone explain a scenario for requirement of PBFT in permission based BCT network.

Answer (score 1):

First you must define the resilience in your system.

Do you expect **Byzantine** behavior from the nodes (i.e. nodes behaving arbitrarily, deviating from the protocol, and possibly intentionally harming the system)? Or you just need the system to be **crash**-fault tolerant? (i.e. nodes going to sleep, offline or disconnecting).

If you stick to the higher "Byzantine" resilience, you are most likely looking at a PBFT-variant consensus, assuming your system is permissioned (i.e. only nodes with the right credentials can participate in the consensus protocol). In most cases, the requirement for a "safe" and "live" consensus is 66% "honest" nodes. On the other hand, if you just assume crash-tolerance, then the requirement is 51% "online" nodes.

A real example is Hyperledger, where some of its frameworks are only crash-fault tolerant (e.g. Hyperledger Fabric) but others are also Byzantine-fault tolerant (e.g. Hyperledger Indy).

Comment: Thanks nicely explained.